# how to create complex json using json_model pakage flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, jsonmodel

```
"masses": [
  {
      "Sunday": 
      
      
      [
          {
              "mass_timing": "7.00 AM",
              "mass_place": "First Mass",
              "mass_note": "English Mass"
          },
          {
              "mass_timing": "7.00 AM",
              "mass_place": "First Mass",
              "mass_note": "English Mass"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "Monday": [
          {
              "mass_timing": "7.00 AM",
              "mass_place": "First Mass",
              "mass_note": "English Mass"
          },
          {
              "mass_timing": "7.00 AM",
              "mass_place": "First Mass",
              "mass_note": "English Mass"
          }
      ]
  }  ]
```

My JSON is like this I need to create a JSON model using the package json_model

can anyone help me to create the json_model dynamic json file to generate json serialization

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using https://app.quicktype.io/ as it's as it's name says, very quick and you don't need to add a package in your project but of course you need some little modifications on your model to customize it on your case, just choose dart and enjoy.